# Arquivos para configurações no nodejs

Tags: node.js

Estou tentando realizar um arquivo com as configurações mas não sei ainda muito bem como realizar isso, dessa forma pesquisando diversos conteúdos, encontrei algumas recursos onde me facilita mas não seria o meu caso.

Pensei em utilizar variáveis globais para essa operação mas observei que elas não seriam tão viáveis, devido a alguns fóruns que li.

Eu criei um arquivo e exporto essas informações para algumas rotas onde eu preciso. Essas informações são por exemplo um e-mail do usuário onde ele irá utilizar para receber informações do sistema, o usuário pode trocar esse e-mail a qualquer momento, dessa forma coloquei esses dados dentro da minha base de dados em uma collection, destinada a somente configurações (atualmente estou utilizando o MongoDB) ou seja, é salvo somente um documento referente a essa configuração.

Em meu arquivo eu utilizo o findOne para buscar esse documento na minha base de dados e depois passar essas informações para exportar, eu até consegui realizar isso de certa forma, mas ficou um pouco "estranho" de se entender e compreender, e queria saber se existe uma possibilidade de fazer isso forma mais simples.

config.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const router = require("../routes/alunos")

// Model de configuração
require("../models/Configuracao")
const Configuracao = mongoose.model("configuracoes")

const configs = []

Configuracao.findOne().lean().then(config => {
    configs.push(config)

})

module.exports = {
    configs: configs
}
```

Aqui basicamente estou fazendo com que o meu model seja puxado para a array e depois eu passo essa informação para a rota que desejo

configuracoes.js - essa seria minha rota

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const config = require("../config/config");

require("../models/Configuracao")
const Configuracao = mongoose.model("configuracoes")



router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(config.configs[0]["_id"])
    res.render('configuracoes/configuracoes')
})
```

Dessa forma é retornado o ID corretamente do meu documento, mas acho que isso está um pouco estranho.

Teria alguma forma de realizar isso que desejo de outro método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar o async e await nessa questão

config.js

```
const configuracoes = async () => {
    const configuracoes = await Configuracao.findOne()
    return configuracoes
}

module.exports = {
    configuracoes: configuracoes()
}
```

configuracoes.js

```
const config = require("../config/config");

require("../models/Configuracao")
const Configuracao = mongoose.model("configuracoes")

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let configuracoes = await config.configuracoes
    console.log(configuracoes._id)
    res.render('configuracoes/configuracoes')
})
```